# How can I add link to json_encode?

Tags: php, jquery

How can I add clickable link to json_encode?

I did a multiple query auto complete textbox with jquery. Maybe that's not the correct way how to do multiple queries but that's works anyway.

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_SERVER.";port=3306;dbname=".DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM azonositok WHERE guid LIKE :term');
        $stmt->execute(array('term' => '%'.$_GET['term'].'%'));

        while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
            $return_arr[] =  $row['guid']; /// I want to link to http://example.com/guid.php

        }
        $stmt1 = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM felhasznalok WHERE fnev LIKE :term');
        $stmt1->execute(array('term' => '%'.$_GET['term'].'%'));

        while($row1 = $stmt1->fetch()) {
            $return_arr[] =  $row1['fnev']; /// I want to link to http://example.com/profile.php
        }

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'HIBA: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }


    echo json_encode($return_arr);
}
```

Comment: JSON is just a string format representing a JavaScript data structure. You can put anything you like in it really. For something to be _"clickable"_ though depends on the interpretation of that string

Comment: If you have stored `http://example.com` and same data is retrieved, to make the link clickable, standard HTML link code should be followed. After that json string is returned, add `<a href=' before the URL, add `'>Description of Link</a>` after the URL, full string will become `<a href='http://example.com>Description of LInk</a>`

Comment: Already tried that. But it's not works. Here is the result if I do that: https://i.imgur.com/ADoFq65.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to add a function to execute on selection of an item in the autocomplete widget's dropdown list.

This is done with the select property as follows:

```
$(".auto").autocomplete({
    source: "search.php",
    minLength: 1,
    select: function(event, ui) { 
        window.location.href = ui.item.value;
    }
});
```

This changes the current window's location to the selected item's value.

EDIT:
To change the default behavior where the value is displayed on focus/select to display the label instead, you could try:

```
$(".auto").autocomplete({
    source: "search.php",
    minLength: 1,
    select: function(event, ui) { 
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.auto').val(ui.item.label);
        window.location.href = ui.item.value;
    },
    focus: function(event, ui) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.auto').val(ui.item.label);
    }
});
```

Comment: Already tried that. But it's not works. Here is the result if I do that: 
 https://i.imgur.com/ADoFq65.png

Comment: Are you using jQuery UI's autocomplete?

Comment: Um, I'm used this tutorial: https://daveismyname.blog/autocomplete-with-php-mysql-and-jquery-ui

Comment: I've edited the answer according to that tutorial. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, it works but as I comment out in my question I want to seperate the "guid" & the "profile" urls. It's possible? so if the result is guid then go to example.com/guid.php if the result is fnev then go to example.com/profile.php

Comment: Do you mean when the `azonositok` table has a result, it should use the `guid` column and not check the `felhasznalok` table as well?

Comment: No. Currently I have 2 queries right from azonositok table and from felhasznalok table. If in the textbox search results display a guid and click into that then I want to redirect the user to a guid page like: example.com/guid.php but if the search results display an username (fnev) and user click into that then redirect to example.com/profile.php. Short explain: If the search result from the guid table and user clik then redirect to example.com/guid.php else if the result from fnev table then redirect to example.com/profile.php.

Comment: Maybe something like `$return_arr[] =  ['value' => 'http://example.com/guid.php', 'label' => $row['guid']];` instead of just `$return_arr[] =  $row['guid'];`. This will display the guid in the label, but redirect to  `http://example.com/guid.php`.

Comment: Yes! That's was what I want to do. One more thing, now if I click to the result then it's fill the textbox with the value (example.com/guid/xyz123456789) and after then redirect to the guid page. Can I hide that? Or just remove the link before the guid and shows only the guid? So if I click then don't fill or shows just the (xyz123456789) in the textbox and redirect to the guid page. Huh sorry for my bad english.

Comment: I've added a bit of code to the answer that seems to work.